# Pandas: how to do value counts within groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe. I want to group by `a` and `b` first. Within each group, I need to do a value count based on `c` and only pick the one with most counts. If there are more than one c values for one group with the most counts, just pick any one.

```
a    b    c
1    1    x
1    1    y
1    1    y
1    2    y
1    2    y
1    2    z
2    1    z
2    1    z
2    1    a
2    1    a
```

The expected result would be

```
a    b    c
1    1    y
1    2    y
2    1    z
```

What is the right way to do it? It would be even better if I can print out each group with c's value counts sorted as an intermediate step.

Comment: why does `a = 2` has 2 entries `z` and `a`  for same `b=1` ?

Comment: @anky there are lots of duplicates in the data, not just for `a` and `b` but for `a`, `b` and `c` too. Part of the reason of doing this is to remove most of the duplicates

Comment: I get your point , but as per your question -  *If there are more than one c values for one group with the most counts, just pick any one* , so `a=2` and `b=1` group has both `z` and `a` appearing twice , hence shouldnt just 1 be taken in the output?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

group the original dataframe by `['a', 'b']` and get the `.max()` should work

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].max()
```

you can also aggregate `'count'` and `'max'` values

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].agg({'max': max, 'count': 'count'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: I know this is the final result I wanted but is there a way to sort `c`'s occurrences within a group first?

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for [`.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```py
df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].value_counts()
```

```
a  b  c
1  1  y    2
      x    1
   2  y    2
      z    1
2  1  a    2
      z    2
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df=df.groupby(["a", "b", "c"])["c"].count().sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index(name="dropme").drop_duplicates(subset=["a", "b"], keep="first").drop("dropme", axis=1)
```

Outputs:

```py
   a  b  c
0  2  1  z
2  1  2  y
3  1  1  y
```